# How can I add multiple skins to Minecraft (Windows 10 edition)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to add downloaded Minecraft skins to a folder so I can switch between them easily in the game?

I've located a 'skin_packs' folder within the game folder: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\skin_packs`

Can this folder be used in some way? I've tried copying some skins there but they don't display in the skin selector, in game... Is there any way of doing this? Or is the folder above just for purchased skin packs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add multiple skins to Minecraft.

What you can do is create a folder anywhere on your computer (preferably Documents) and create a new folder called "Skins" and *add* all of your skins their, then on the **Minecraft Windows 10** *main menu*, select the **Hanger** icon and select "**Choose new Skin**" *navigate* to the folder you created with all your skins and select the skin you want.

> Then next time you change your skin, you will *automatically* start in
>   that folder ***you*** created, making it **easy** to quickly locate the skin you
>   would like to use next time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know how to do that, but I just wondered if there was a way to view the skin previews in the game, rather than selecting them 1 at a time to see what they look like.

I'm currently having issues when I choose a new skin - the new skin doesn't display and I have to exit the game and reload to view the skin that was selected.

I'll accept your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a way to make custom skin packs now there tutorials out there that are way to complicated for people to do and there is to much work. But anyway I made a tutorial of how to make skin packs with the skins you want. Here is the link:

. But the reason there is a skin_pack folder in the game files is because the creators of the game expected people to want to have their own skin packs that they made by themself but they dont explain or hint how to make it. Marketlplace skin packs that you can buy dont appear in the folder because they are online and connected to your microsoft account.